# Exoplayer exception appearing too lately

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I am trying to learn exoplayer.So far I am able to play a mediasource with exoplayer. I want to show an error dialouge if any mediasource can not be played. the error dialouge is appearing but taking a bit time. so I tried to handle the response time the following way but no improvement.

```
  if (channelUrl != null && !channelUrl.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(channelUrl));
                DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory();
                HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem);
                player.setMediaSource(hlsMediaSource);
                player.prepare();
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                player.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPlayerError(@NonNull PlaybackException error) {
                        Log.e("ExoPlayer", "Error playing media: " + error.getMessage());

                        // Delay the error dialog by 3 seconds
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
                            showAlertDialogError();
                            player.stop();
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```